# Как с помощью питона узнать системную тему Windows?

Tags: python, windows, ос, реестр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно уметь возвращать эти три значения в этих ячейках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти параметры хранятся в реестре ОС по адресу

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize
```

[image: параметры темы]

Собственно, вам нужно получить эти значения.

Не ас в питоне, но для работы, как понимаю, вам понадобится модуль winreg. Вот минимальный вариант программы, полную обработку ошибок сделайте сами:

```
    import winreg
    reg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
    reg_path = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize'
    try:
        reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(reg, reg_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:

# Обработка ошибки, если нет пути

    for i in range(1024):
        try:
            value_name, value, _ = winreg.EnumValue(reg_key, i)
            if value_name == 'SystemUsesLightTheme':
# нашли ключ темы ОС по умолчанию, проверяем 0 или 1, используем, как надо        
        except:
            break
# данные закончились
```

Ну, и следует помнить, что если какого-то из представленных ключей не нашлось, то используется режим по умолчанию. Для темы это значит, что она "не тёмная" :)